# Using shortcodes within PayPal forms

Tags: forms, paypal, shortcode, auto-populate

I set up a PayPal form with hidden fields in order to collect user information on PayPal and cross-reference what users had paid for a specific item.

After the most recent updates, the shortcodes I used stopped working within the form.

Now the information saved is actually the text of the shortcode, not the output of the shortcode information.

An example of the form code looks like this:

```
<input name="os0" value="[wpv-current-user]">
```

This used to collect the username, but since the update, the information it collects is the text "[wpv-current-user]" even though, when outside the form, the shortcode works just fine and will display the username.

Any suggestions?

Comment: shouldn't the input has `type` like `<input type="text" name="os0" value="[wpv-current-user]">`

Comment: Yes, I left it out, but it works the same either way.